# Makefile $(eval $(call)) function

Tags: foreach, makefile, eval, call

simple code in makefile

```
define fun
@echo this is function
endef

78 all:
79   $(foreach objdir, $(OBJECTDIRS), $(eval $(call fun)))
```

**the err message is :
Makefile:79:*** missing separator.  Stop.**

Note: i have checked the $(OBJECTDIRS) is not empty and $(oobjdir) too

if i change the code to flowing lines:

```
define fun
@echo this is function
endef

all:
 $(call fun())
```

then it's running good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The make `eval` function evaluates the text you give is *as a makefile* (expects makefile sytnax).

The text `@echo this is a function` is NOT a makefile.

In other words, if you create a Makefile and you put into it the text:

```
@echo this is a function
```

(by itself, with nothing else) and you run `make` on that makefile, you'll get this same `missing separator` error.